# Box optimization with three variables (Julia Optim.jl)

Tags: optimization, julia

I am trying to optimize a function with respect to 3 variables using the optimize function of Optim.jl. I am using NelderMead as my objective does not have a gradient and the Fminbox method as I know the lower and upper bounds. The chunk of code looks like this:

```
lower_bound = [0.93,0.01,1.0001]
upper_bound = [0.999,1.0,1.05]
init_val = [0.99,0.15,1.005]
result = optimize(moments_norm, lower_bound, upper_bound, init_val, Fminbox(NelderMead()))
```

It gives me the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching +(::Float64, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...) at operators.jl:529
  +(::Float64, !Matched::Float64) at float.jl:401
  +(::AbstractFloat, !Matched::Bool) at bool.jl:106
  ...
```

Note that `moment_norm` is the nontrivial objective function that yields an expression similar as `ax+by+cz` with (a,b,c) constant and (x,y,z) moments that depend on the variables I optimize over.

A previous version of my code worked perfectly fine when I only optimized over 2 variables instead of 3.

Comment: This is very hard to debug without running code - can you try to whittle down `moment_norm` to an MWE?

Comment: unfortunately moment_norm is a very complicated function that draws from other functions that rely on more than a thousand lines of code. So I don't think I can provide something that will run but I can give you more details on the function output itself: it's a weighted sum of differences between estimated variables from the model and data points. The output is: norm=a**gininorm + b*CsYnorm + c*IsYnorm where a = b = c = 1 and gininorm = (estimated_gini - data_gini) and so forth. It was working fine with only 2 moments but adding the third breaks it.

Comment: You probably have a bug in `moments_norm`. If I run dummy `moments_norm(x) = sum(x -> x^2, x)` there is no problem with finding the solution.

Comment: The parameters are in a different order. Check [the docs](http://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/v0.9.3/user/minimization/#box-minimization) it should be `optimize(moments_norm, init_val, lower_bound, upper_bound, etc)`